# How to get multiple inputs from a scanner and assign the numbers to a value?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

In this programming assignment, I need to use bit operators on two numbers that the user gives. First of I need to get inputs a and b from a single input. Here is what I am using for it:

```
Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a and b numbers between the "
            + "interval [-128,127] (-1 -1 to exit): ");

    byte[] userInput = new byte[2];

    for(byte i = 0; i < userInput.length; i++) {
        userInput[i] = stdin.nextByte();
    }
```

I can't find a way to compare the two numbers that are given. Here is what the output is somewhat suppose to look like:

enter a and b numbers in the interval [-128,127] (-1 -1 to exit): 59 18

How do I assign the two input numbers to a and b so I can later use them for my bit wise operators?

Comment: `a=userInput[0]` and `b=userInput[1]`

Answer (score 1):

As Pavneet Singh mentions

```
a=userInput[0]
b=userInput[1]
```

should work. Or to avoid using an array you could do:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter a and b numbers between the "
        + "interval [-128,127] (-1 -1 to exit): ");

byte a = stdin.nextByte();
byte b = stdin.nextByte();


}
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.print("Enter a and b numbers between the interval [-128,127] (-1 -1 to exit): ");

String inputString = stdin.nextLine();

String[] inputArray = inputString.split(" ");

byte a = Byte.parseByte(inputArray[0]);
byte b = Byte.parseByte(inputArray[1]);
```

Comment: Thank you this is very helpful